# Is 75-200 mircroseconds RTT normal for a 15 char string sent through TCP?

Tags: c++, docker, google-cloud-platform, networking, tcp

im developping a simple project to calculate RTT (ping) and monitor it in real-time. Im using cpp for both client and server. The client is executed on my machine while the server is hosted on a google cloud VM as a docker container.

The problem is that the pings that i calculate seems curiously low (between 75 and 200 microseconds).
Which is also approximatively the time i obtained when both client and server were ran on the same machine.

I thought sending the same string through TCP but to an external server would make the RTT longer but it's not, im wondering if it's my comprehension of TCP or networks in general or a mistake in my code.

Here is my client.cpp

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <matplot/matplot.h>


#define PORT 8080
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET clientSocket;
    sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    const char* helloMessage = "Hello from client";
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if ((clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cerr << "Could not create socket.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    if (InetPton(AF_INET, "MY GCLOUD IP", &serverAddr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
        std::cerr << "Invalid address/Address not supported.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Connection failed.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    double iteration = 0;
    std::vector<double> iterations;
    std::vector<double> pings;

    using namespace matplot;

    line_handle fig = plot(iterations, pings);

    fig.get()->display_name("Real-time ping monitoring");

    while(TRUE) {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        send(clientSocket, helloMessage, strlen(helloMessage), 0);

        int recvSize = recv(clientSocket, buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        int64_t ping = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count();
        buffer[recvSize] = '\0';

        std::cout << "Server: " << buffer << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Time elapsed: " << ping << "us\n";


        pings.push_back(ping);
        iterations.push_back(++iteration);

        try {
            fig.get()->x_data(iterations);
            fig.get()->y_data(pings);
            fig.get()->touch();
        } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
            std::cerr << "Caught a runtime_error exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
        }

        Sleep(1000);
    }

    closesocket(clientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

ANd my server.cpp

```
`#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>

#define PORT 8080
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int serverSocket;

void cleanUpOnCrash(int sig) {
    close(serverSocket);
    std::cout << "Server closed\n";
    exit(0);
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, cleanUpOnCrash);

    sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    socklen_t clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);

    // Create a socket
    if ((serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Could not create socket.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Bind the socket to an IP address and port
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    if (bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Bind failed.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Listen for incoming connections
    listen(serverSocket, 3);

    // Accept a client connection
    while(1){
        std::cout << "Waiting for incoming connections...\n";
        int clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &clientAddrSize);
        if (clientSocket == -1) {
            std::cerr << "Accept failed.\n";
            return 1;
        }
        std::cout << "Connection accepted.\n";

        // Send a welcome message to the client
        const char* welcomeMessage = "Welcome to the server!\n";
        send(clientSocket, welcomeMessage, strlen(welcomeMessage), 0);

        // Echo back any messages received from the client
        int recvSize;
        while ((recvSize = recv(clientSocket, buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, 0)) > 0) {
            buffer[recvSize] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the received string before printing
            std::cout << "Client: " << buffer << std::endl;
            send(clientSocket, buffer, recvSize, 0);
        }

        // Clean up
        close(clientSocket);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I confirm that i get the logs on my VM so im not mistakenly sending my string through a running local server.

Comment: Your client doesn't appear to be checking the values returned by its `send()` or `recv()` calls.  If you don't check those values, you don't know how many bytes were actually sent (or received).  It might even be that one or both of those calls are returning -1/error, which would certainly explain why they return quickly.

Comment: Network traffic cannot exceed the speed of light. Measure the distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't measure RTT, which would be sending a message and waiting for the reply to this specific message.

Instead you measure the time it takes you to `send` a message to the OS kernel and to `recv` an **previously** sent message from the server, i.e. you are not reading the reply to the message you've just send but instead you read the previously send welcome message from the server. This welcome message was send by the server immediately after the accept, so it might have been already been processed by your OS and put into the socket buffer. So at the end you've measured the time it takes to put a message into the socket write buffer (`send`) and to read an existing on out of the socket receive buffer (`recv`) - which are all local operations.

To detect such kind of mistake make sure that the message received is actually the expected reply to the message you've just send and not something else.

Comment: An easy way to do this is to put the send time into the message. So when you receive a message, just subtract that time from the current time and you have the RTT, after checking that it is one of your messages as Steffen suggests above.